# Web Share API - Share Image

Tags: android, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I'm working on a PWA, which is a share-target as specified in the manifest.json. This PWA is installed (to the Homescreen) on my Android 8.1 device with Chrome 73 for Android.

When sharing web pages, this seems to work. I successfully receive the `title` and `text` parameters. Due to limitations of Android, I don't know if I'm ever getting the `url` parameter.

However, when sharing images specifically (so not just pages, links, text) by long-clicking an image in Chrome, and press "Share Image" - my PWA does not show up in the list of possible targets. Dropbox, Bluetooth, Telegram etc. do show up, but my PWA does not.

Question: how can I make my PWA show up for "Share Image" sharing?

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "share_target": {
    "action": "/#/share-target/",
    "method": "GET",
    "enctype": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "params": {
      "title": "title",
      "text": "text",
      "url": "url",
      "files": [{
        "name": "file",
        "accept": ["*/*"]
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Changing to `POST` does not seem to work either:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "share_target": {
    "action": "/#/share-target/",
    "method": "POST",
    "enctype": "multipart/form-data",
    "params": {
      "title": "title",
      "text": "text",
      "url": "url",
      "files": [{
        "name": "file",
        "accept": ["*/*"]
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware, no browsers support images for the Web Share API.

Comment: Basically trying to reproduce https://youtu.be/lNOP5dcLZF4?t=773 where it seems at least somewhat possible.

Comment: The video description says "just landing in Chrome Canary" so you probably need Chrome 75 or 76.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is a old question, but for anyone looking I've found [here](https://web.dev/web-share-target/) that support for sharing files was added in chrome 76.

> Support for text and data was added in Chrome 71, and support for
>   files was added in Chrome 76.